# VMWare keyboard not recognised by host although input is working fine

Tags: bluetooth, vmware

I'm using a Mac Yosemite virtual machine on VMware, and I get this screen that says it's looking for a wireless keyboard (Bluetooth) because it didn't recognise a wired one. However, my normal keyboard input is working fine, as I am able to login. For some reason, I can't get this window to close on the login screen. Is this a problem others have faced?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve similar issue by changing the USB compatibility setting to USB 2.0

[image]